# É possível integrar pagamentos no meu sistema com instituições bancárias?

Tags: api, pagamento-online

Olá, estou com um problema: preciso fazer uma quantia em dinheiro ser depositada na conta de uma determinada pessoa, a partir do meu sistema, que eu implementei.

Preciso saber se é possível realizar pagamentos ou transferências entre contas, a partir do meu sistema. Preciso poder fazer uma transferência bancária ou depósito, informando o valor e a conta de destino. Pode ser qualquer banco.

Caso não exista essa possibilidade, existe algum tipo de carteira online (semelhante ao Neteller, por exemplo) que eu possa efetuar transferências e checar o saldo ou o extrato via API?

Grato!

Comment: Você tem que perguntar para o banco que você opera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, basta utilizar um gateway de pagamento. Faça uma pesquisa no google, e veja qual dos que existem no mercado, o que mais atende a sua necessidade. Eles vão te oferecer uma biblioteca para você integrar a api deles em seu sistema e a maioria oferece também um suporte para implementação. Porém você que vai ter que lidar com os riscos da transação, diferente de quando se usa um integrador de pagamento (paypal, moip, boacompra).

Se você não estiver pronto para assumir esses riscos, pode contratar um integrador de pagamento em vez de um gateway. Eles assumem todo o risco das transações, e outras dores de cabeça, mas cobram uma taxa de serviço mais elevada também.

O integrador não faz depósito direto em conta, o usuário teria que criar uma conta no site do integrador, e depois resgatar o dinheiro na conta dele. Se você precisa de depósito direto na conta bancária, a melhor opção é usar o gateway de pagamento.

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateway_de_pagamento

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Podemos conversar melhor fora daqui? Tenho muitas dúvidas. edgar.froes@gmail.com

Comment: Claro. Enviei um convite pelo google hangout