# Aceitar pagamento via Cartão de Crédito via PHP com SSL

Tags: php, api, integração, pagamento-online

Tenho um sistema, que faz cobrança recorrente dos meus clientes. Já aceito boleto bancário.

Agora quero aceitar pagamento via cartão de crédito (NÃO POR PAGSEGURO,PAYPAL, ETC) quero diretamente com a operadora de cartão...

Já tenho servidor com SSL, tudo pronto..

Agora preciso saber os passos para conseguir aceitar cartão de crédito!

Obrigado desde já!!

Comment: Não acho que as operadoras de cartão ofereçam esse tipo de serviço, o mais correto seria fazer com alguma representante acho que Cielo é a mais fácil de lidar nesse quesito

Comment: Fazer na mão seria bem complexo... Recomendo utilizar integrações com checkout transparente, onde o pagamento é realizado no seu site, sem redirecionamento. Por conta de que, você traria para si, talvez, muitos transtornos com usuários e em caso de clonagem de cartão, roubo de dados e etc... As responsabilidade cairiam todas sobre você, e sem contar do marketing por tras por exemplo do PagSeguro, as pessoas se sentem mais seguras por conta da Marca...

Comment: Além da indicada no link acima, tem essa: [É possível integrar pagamentos no meu sistema com instituições bancárias?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124395/70)

Comment: Cara, existe o script para pagamento com cartão de crédito pronto e é bem tranquilo de implementar!

Neste link está tudo pronto e você vai ter que ficar esquentando cabeça.

Dá uma olhada.

Exemplo funcionando:

https://datafacilinformatica.com.br/script-em-php-para-pagamento-com-cartao-de-creditos/

https://www.datafacilinformatica.com.br/venda/script-para-integraco-com-cielo-php-cielo-ecommerce.php

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Para tal necessita de um gateway de pagamento.

Nenhuma operadora ou banco fornece tal serviço de forma direta ao consumidor final. Sempre existe um gateway que é o intermediário.

O Paypal, por exemplo, oferece o [Direct Payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/direct-payment/). É válido somente para contas do Paypal do tipo business localizadas no Reino Unido.

Nada o impede de negociar diretamente com os bancos ou diretamente com as operadoras de cartão. Se tem influência, grana, tempo e disposição para tal, vá em frente. Mas provavelmente não conseguirá nada pois o padrão do mercado é usar os gateways para a finalidade descrita na pergunta.

O primeiro passo seria escolher um gateway. Após isso siga as instruções do gateway escolhido. Alguns gateways mais modernos fornecem recursos onde não há necessidade em enviar dados do cartão para o seu servidor e processá-los no backend. Mas a maioria é feito dessa forma, o que torna a segurança mais delicada. Nesse ponto envolve muito a questão ética pois um administrador do servidor ou o programador que criou e mantem o sistema e até o dono do sistema podem agir de má fé roubar os dados dos próprios clientes.

Além disso, sites desse tipo são os preferidos para ações de hackers.

Para reduzir o peso sobre responasbilidade, não guarde dados dos cartões nos seus servidores. Use-os apenas para a transação no momento.

É também muito importante entender os padrões de segurança e ética. Para isso consulte: https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/

https://www.pcicomplianceguide.org/pci-faqs-2/